# « Arachide » et « cacahuète » désignent-ils la même chose?

Tags: traduction, noms, botanique

À l'école, j'ai appris que la traduction française de « peanut » était « cacahuète » (ou « cacahouette »). Aujourd'hui, je partage une chambre d'hôtel avec une Canadienne qui a emporté ça:

[image: beurre d'arachide]

Il me semble que les mots *arachide* et *cacahuète* veulent dire la même chose. Est-ce que l'un est plus correct que l'autre ? Est-ce qu'il y a une différence de sens, ou d'usage géographique ?

Comment: J'ai noté ça dans le meta, mais ça mérite un peu de répétition - mon français est tellement rouillé. Je sais que je fais des erreurs, et ça ne me vexera pas d'être corrigée quand c'est nécessaire... donc, si cette question a besoin des révision, allez-y, s'il vous plaît!

Comment: Au Québec, on emploie familièrement *pinotte* (vient de *peanut*) et non arachide ou cacahuète.

Comment: Je note que l'article [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Arachide&diff=cur&oldid=73657005) a changé et ne dit plus les choses comme en [2011](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Arachide&oldid=73657005); le fait qu'on désigne le fruit plus souvent _cacahuète_ signifie-t-il absolument que ce terme soit pour le fruit et l'_arachide_ pour la plante ?

Comment: Ce genre de distinction existe également pour d'autres plantes, comme le chanvre par exemple.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

La *[cacahuète](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cacahu%C3%A8te)* est le fruit ou la graine, et la plante s'appelle *[arachide](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/arachide)*. En tout cas, c'est la distinction usuelle en France. Le terme de loin [le plus fréquent](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=cacahu%C3%A8te%2Ccacahou%C3%A8te%2Carachide&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3) est *arachide*. La plante s'est même appelée autrefois *pistache de terre*; cette expression a [quasiment disparu au XX<sup>e</sup> siècle (au moins à l'écrit)](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=pistache+de+terre&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3).

Pour les produits dérivés, j'ai l'habitude de voir en France *beurre de cacahuète(s)* ([mais Google Ngram montre plus de beurre d'arachide](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=beurre+de+cacahu%C3%A8te%2Cbeurre+de+cacahou%C3%A8te%2Cbeurre+de+cacahu%C3%A8tes%2Cbeurre+de+cacahou%C3%A8tes%2Cbeurre+d%27arachide&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3)) mais *huile d'arachide* ([sans conteste](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=huile+de+cacahu%C3%A8te%2Chuile+de+cacahou%C3%A8te%2Chuile+de+cacahu%C3%A8tes%2Chuile+de+cacahou%C3%A8tes%2Chuile+d%27arachide&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3)). Pour le beurre, j'ai l'impression qu'on a tendance à parler de cacahuètes en France et d'arachide au Québec et en Afrique.

Pour ce qui est de l'utilisation imagée *peanuts* pour désigner une quantité dérisoire, j'ai déjà rencontré *des cacahuètes*, mais c'est très peu fréquent ; il y a d'autres expressions beaucoup plus courantes, comme *des prunes* ou *des clopes* (un peu plus familières que l'anglais *peanuts*), ou *une bagatelle* (soutenu, un peu vieilli).

Comment: « Des cacahuètes », il me semble que je ne le dirais que pour une valeur, pas n'importe quelle petite quantité.  Mais mon opinion ne vaut peut-être pas un radis.

Comment: Il m'a semblé que *des cacahuètes*, dans le sens de *très peu*, a priori, ne se réserve que pour des considérations de salaire, alors que le contexte d'utilisation de *peanuts* en anglais est beaucoup plus large. (C'est d'ailleurs pourquoi on entend assez fréquemment l'anglicisme.)

Comment: Je suis allergique aux cacahuètes et ai toujours pensé que l'arachide était quelque chose de plus général. En particulier, je pensais à tort que les noisettes et les pistaches faisaient partis de la famille des arachides.

Answer (score 10):

L'*arachide* c'est la plante, et ses graines sont appelées *cacahuètes* (ou *cacahouètes*, etc…).

Source [wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arachide), qui fournit une belle illustration :

[image: La plante]

En fait, on utilise fréquemment « beurre de cacahuètes » plutôt que « beurre d'arachide ».

Answer (score 5):

La [page wikipédia sur l'arachide](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arachide) est claire et sans appel : *arachide* désigne la plante, le fruit et la graine, alors que *cacahuète* (ou *cacahouète*) désigne uniquement la graine. Bref, c'est kif-kif.

Comment: Sans appel, c'est vite dit (d'ailleurs, si ça avait été le cas, la bonne réaction aurait été de clore la question). Et le beurre, il compte pour du beurre ?

Comment: @Gilles: j'ai voté pour clore :)

Comment: Si tu votes pour clore, [tu ne devrais pas répondre](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104127/what-is-more-correct-when-i-see-this-type-of-questions).

Comment: @Gilles puisque la communauté juge que la question doit rester ouverte, pourquoi ne devrais-je pas répondre ? Ma réponse peut-être migrée en commentaire si la question est fermée (c'est ce qui se passe sur EL&U). Surtout pour une question suspectée d'être une « general reference ».

Answer (score 1):

J'habite au Canada mais je suis anglophone, et je n'ai jamais entendu le mot cacahuète avant qu'il y a quelques minutes. Ici (parce que au Canada les produits sont tous étiquetés en français et en'anglais), nous achetons des arachides, des beures d'arachides ou farines d'arachides. Peut-être les Québecois disent « Pinottes » mais cacahuètes? Je pense que non.

Comment: Il paraiît que les canadiens disent 'arachides' preque toujours et les français, 'cacahuètes'?

Comment: (Québécois) J'utilise beaucoup plus fréquemment *Peanut* (Pinotte) que ces autres mots. Cependant, *Peanut* est aussi utilisé pour référer toute sorte de noix. Par exemple, au lieu de parler d'un pot de noix (mélangés), on va le nommer un pot de *peanut*. Le terme *Arachides* est usuellement utilisé pour un « Beurre d'arachide », tandis que cacahuètes est utilisé pour spécifier une petite quantité (une, deux, une poignée, etc)  de *peanut*. J'ai aussi souvent entendu ce mot dans un contexte de zoo.. (« Ne pas donner de cacahuètes au animaux! ») (Pas assez de chars disponible pour continuer)

Answer (score 1):

Au Canada français, on dit en effet souvent «pinotte», qui vient de l'anglais «peanut». Quand on veut «bien» parler, on dit «arachide» : beurre d'arachides, manger des arachides ... alors que l'arachide, comme il a été dit plus haut, c'est la plante dont le fruit est la cacahuète.

Il est extrêmement rare qu'on emploie le mot «cacahuète» au Québec (et dans le reste du Canada français). Pourquoi ? Ma théorie (qui vaut ce qu'elle vaut), c'est que le mot cacahuète ne s'est jamais implanté chez nous à cause des ses deux premières syllabes, jugées ... scatologiques.

Answer (score 0):

Les cacahuètes sont des aliments que l'on ramasse dans la terre (un peu comme les pommes de terre) ou que l'on cueille, suivant la famille.
Le beurre de cacahuète est fait avec des cacahuètes écrasées.
L'arachide fait partie d'une espèce de végétaux propre à fournir de l'huile.

Comment: A vous lire, on dirait que d'autres plantes que l'arachide produisent des cacahuètes. Si c'est le cas, auriez-vous une référence fiable ?